# How can I write this procedure differently

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want to write the following procedure differently so i can call it to return data as if it were a table by doing: `SELECT * FROM table(package.get7DayCapacityDemandProv(1, sysdate))`

**Procesdure:**

```
 PROCEDURE get7DayCapacityDemandProv(p_H_id                  IN     work_entity_data.H_id%TYPE
                                     ,p_date                         IN     DATE
                                     ,p_capacity_day_1                  OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_demand_day_1                    OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_capacity_day_2                  OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_demand_day_2                    OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_capacity_day_3                  OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_demand_day_3                    OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_capacity_day_4                  OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_demand_day_4                    OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_capacity_day_5                  OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_demand_day_5                    OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_capacity_day_6                  OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_demand_day_6                    OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_capacity_day_7                  OUT NUMBER
                                     ,p_demand_day_7                    OUT NUMBER
                                     )
  IS
  BEGIN

    getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(p_H_id
                                  ,p_date
                                  ,p_capacity_day_1
                                  ,p_demand_day_1
                                  );

    getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(p_H_id
                                  ,p_date + 1
                                  ,p_capacity_day_2
                                  ,p_demand_day_2
                                  );

    getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(p_H_id
                                  ,p_date + 2
                                  ,p_capacity_day_3
                                  ,p_demand_day_3
                                  );

    getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(p_H_id
                                  ,p_date + 3
                                  ,p_capacity_day_4
                                  ,p_demand_day_4
                                  );

    getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(p_H_id
                                  ,p_date + 4
                                  ,p_capacity_day_5
                                  ,p_demand_day_5
                                  );

    getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(p_H_id
                                  ,p_date + 5
                                  ,p_capacity_day_6
                                  ,p_demand_day_6
                                  );

    getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(p_H_id
                                  ,p_date + 6
                                  ,p_capacity_day_7
                                  ,p_demand_day_7
                                  );

  END get7DayCapacityDemandProv;
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the SELECT to return one row with 14 columns, or do you want it to return 7 rows, one for each day, with 2 columns each?

Comment: @dave edit: ideally i would like 3 columsn and7 rows. columns = day, capacity, demand. row= day1, day2, day3 etc. so i can put it in a graph. if not then whatever you can think of i just want ot get it out of the procedure and into a table i can select from

Answer (score 2):

You want to (1) convert this to a function that returns a record, and then (2) convert that to a pipelined function.

Here's an example.  I've left out the first parameter just so I could easily run it, but you can just add that back in.

```
create or replace package test
as
  type theRecordType is record (
     day  date,
     capacity  number,
     demand  number
  );

  type theTableType is table of theRecordType;

  function getData(p_date DATE) return theTableType pipelined;
end test;
/

create or replace package body test
as
  function getData(p_date DATE) return theTableType pipelined
    as
      theRecord  theRecordType;
    begin
      for i in 0..6 loop
        theRecord.date := p_date + i;
        theRecord.capacity := i;
        theRecord.demand := i+1;
        --
        -- you would have a call to your procedure instead of the above two lines
        --      getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(p_H_id
        --                          ,theRecord.date
        --                          ,theRecord.capacity
        --                          ,theRecord.demand
        --                          );
        --
        pipe row (theRecord);
      end loop;
      return;
    end getData;
end test;
/
```

You can now select from the function and get one row for each day.

```
select * from table(test.getData(SYSDATE));
```

I made it a package so the types could be declared within the package header.  Alternatively, you could keep it a standalone function and declare the types within the schema using `CREATE TYPE`.

Comment: edit: having a problem. its giving me an error that getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider must be declared

Comment: Some possible reasons for that error are: the procedure name is misspelled (looks OK to me) or the parameters are of incorrect type (did you declare p_H_id with the correct type?) or the schema where you are building the package does not have access to the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This is off the cuff, so it is not going to be 100% syntactically correct, but it will be conceptually correct.

```
create or replace package bingo IS
TYPE bingoCursor is REF CURSOR;

function get7Days(
    bingoId IN  bingoTable.bingoId%TYPE,
    bingoDate   IN  date)
    return bingoCursor;
end bingo;

create or replace package body bingo IS

function get7Days(
    bingoId IN  bingoTable.bingoId%TYPE,
    bingoDate   IN  date)
    return bingoCursor IS

    sevenDaysContent bingoCursor;
begin
    open sevenDaysContent for
        select day 1 stuff;

        union all

        select day 2 stuff;

        union all

        ... select and union all days 3 - day 7;

    return sevenDaysContent;
end get7Days;
end bingo;
```

Comment: What part of my procedure goes in the select day x bit? im not very familiar with plsql can you make it a little bit more syntactly correct to work with my procedure. thanks

Comment: getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider must contain a select statement.  replace "select day 1 stuff" with that select statement with the appropriate input values for day 1.

Comment: The procedure calls another procedure which then calls many different functions and does calculations so i cant put the select statements there like that

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a function or a view. A procedure's returned data can be caught and used within a SQL script but it requires dumping it into a temp or variable table first.

If your requirement is to be able to just do a `SELECT * FROM something` then you probably want a function or a view.

Comment: Yes, I need a wrapper function. Do you know how i can implement it for this particular precedure?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that returns a sys_refcursor.  An overly simple example:

```
create or replace function BLAH(somevar in varchar2) return sys_refcursor IS
v_result_cur sys_refcursor;
v_query varchar2(4000);
...
begin
...
v_query := 'select field1, field2 from blah';
...
open v_result_cur for v_query;
return v_result_cur;
...
exception
...
end;
```

But I will say this isn't typical.  I would probably use a view (or materialized view), or turn those inner procedures into functions and simply select them, like:

```
select
FN_getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(someVars) as Day1Val,
FN_getCapacityDemandOnDayProvider(someVars2) as Day2Val
from dual;
```